# python-ldap: Unable to find a callback when using GSS-API

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ldap

I am trying to use python-ldap on Windows to query an Active Directory server. This is what I have so far:

```
import ldap
import ldap.sasl

email_address = 'user.name@host.company.com'
ldap_url = 'ldap://domain.company.com:389'
domain = 'domain'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
lo = ldap.initialize(ldap_url)
auth_tokens = ldap.sasl.gssapi('')
lo.sasl_interactive_bind_s('', auth_tokens)
print lo.whoami_s()
base = 'dc=%s,dc=company,dc=com' % domain
scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
filter_str = '(mail=%s)' % email_address
attr_list = None
result = lo.search_s(base, scope, filter_str, attr_list)
print "result = %s" % result
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "question.py", line 11, in <module>
lo.sasl_interactive_bind_s('', auth_tokens)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ldap\ldapobject.py", line 244, in sasl_interactive_bind_s
return self._ldap_call(self._l.sasl_interactive_bind_s,who,auth,RequestControlTuples(serverctrls),RequestControlTuples(clientctrls),sasl_flags)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ldap\ldapobject.py", line 106, in _ldap_call
result = func(*args,**kwargs)
ldap.LOCAL_ERROR: {'info': 'SASL(-1): generic failure: Unable to find a callback: 2', 'desc': 'Local error'}
```

I have used the [LDAP Admin](http://www.ldapadmin.org/download/ldapadmin.html) tool to verify that I can reach the server from my Windows machine.

This is the code for ldap.sasl_interactive_bind_s:

```
def sasl_interactive_bind_s(self,who,auth,serverctrls=None,clientctrls=None,sasl_flags=ldap.SASL_QUIET):
    """
    sasl_interactive_bind_s(who, auth [,serverctrls=None[,clientctrls=None[,sasl_flags=ldap.SASL_QUIET]]]) -> None
    """
    return self._ldap_call(self._l.sasl_interactive_bind_s,who,auth,RequestControlTuples(serverctrls),RequestControlTuples(clientctrls),sasl_flags)
```

SASL_QUIET is the default setting.

Comment: Does this have to run on Windows? If yes, forget about it. Cyrus SASL does not really support Windows, more precisely, it support GSS-API only (MIT Kerberos, Heimdal). There is no SSPI binding. At most you can do is to install KfW (Kerberos for Windows).

Comment: I installed MIT Kerberos for Windows, but I cannot figure out how to configure it. The instructions literally say find a working Linux system and copy the configuration from there.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/kfw-4.0/kfw-4.0/kfw-4.0-help/index.html)?

Comment: Yes. When I try to "Get Ticket", I get an error message dialog that says, "Ticket initialization failed." and "Kerberos 5: Configuration file does not specify default realm (error -1765328160). I don't know how to create a configuration file that specifies the default realm.

Comment: Read the man page of `krb5.conf`. It will tell you about the default realm.

Comment: I read the [krb5 man page](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.11/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html) and I was able to create a krb5.conf file with a default realm and run kinit.exe. Now the ticket manager does not complain about the default realm. However, my script still complains about a missing callback.

Comment: The missing callback is unrelated error to Kerberos. When you pass the callback, you will need the ticket anyway. Try to figure out about the callback. It won't work else -- unfortunately. I can only advise to read the source code of that module and see what it expects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99353/discussion-between-david-cullen-and-michael-o).

Answer (score 0):

Cyrus SASL GSSAPI mechanism does not accept any authentication information except a GSS credential struct at most. The error you see is that the interactive mode requires a callback to supply dummy/default values. You need to set to quiet/non-iternative mode.

Here is the code in C, you probably have to figure it out for Python:

```
rc = ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s(ld, NULL, SASL_MECH,
  NULL, NULL, LDAP_SASL_QUIET, do_interact, NULL);
```

where `do_interact` is:

```
int do_interact(
         LDAP *ld,
         unsigned flags,
         void *defaults,
         void *in )
 {
   sasl_interact_t *interact = in;
   char *sasl_defaults = (char  *)defaults;
   const char *dflt = interact->defresult;
   dflt = sasl_defaults;
   interact->result = (dflt && *dflt) ? dflt : "";
   interact->len = strlen( interact->result );
   return LDAP_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Always remember that GSS-API always requires that you already have performed authentication to network by other/external means, e.g., workstation login, `kinit`, etc.

Comment: I updated my question to show that SASL_QUIET is the default.

Comment: @DavidCullen, the `callback()` function is virtually not documented. All I have found is [this](https://github.com/aarcro/python-ldap/blob/master/Lib/ldap/sasl.py).